# jQuery hover animation will not hide text

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using jQuery for hover over effects. I plan on expanding it from what it is now but I'm having a issue. The issue is I want to hide some text until you hover over that div and then it will show it. Then once you move to a different div it will hide it again?

This is what I have so far. http://jsfiddle.net/UDFw7/

**CSS**

```
.divname {
height: 20px;
width: 300px;
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

**javascript**

```
$('.divname').hover(function() {
$(this).animate({
    height: '40px'
}, 300);
},function() {
$(this).animate({
    height: '20px'
}, 300);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class='divname'>Text Here</div>
<div class='divname'>Text Here <br /> Hidden text until hover over</div>
<div class='divname'>Text Here</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden;` to `.divname`

Comment: That's to simple! Works great!

Comment: The disadvantage is that you cant use a transparent background color.

Comment: That wasn't a requirement though. Anyway, it works fine with a transparent background: http://jsfiddle.net/UDFw7/15/

Comment: @S.Visser good to know. Lucky at this time the div background will be white. :)

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
.divname {
height: 20px;
width: 300px;
border: 1px solid black;
}

.divname span {
    display: hidden;
 }
```

**javascript**

```
$('.divname').hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        height: '40px'
    }, 300);
    $('span', this).css("display", "block");
},function() {
    $(this).animate({
        height: '20px'
    }, 300);
    $('span', this).css("display", "none");
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class='divname'>Text Here</div>
<div class='divname'>Text Here <br /> <span> Hidden text until hover over<spa></div>
<div class='divname'>Text Here</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UDFw7/14/

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a new CSS class for the hidden text, for example:

```
.divname p.hidden {
    display:none;
}
```

Then when you hover over that class you want to display that text, so you need this in your javascript:

```
 $(this).children().show();
```

This will change the display property in order to show the hidden text.

I have made a quick fiddle, its not perfect but its a start: http://jsfiddle.net/UDFw7/3/

You will need to add some to it in order to 'rehide' the element when you hover off.

Answer (score 0):

Change the CSS like below

```
.divname {
height: 20px;
width: 300px;
border: 1px solid black;
overflow-y: hidden;
```

}